# Add Customcell in FullCalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

Is it possible to add columns based in this image in `fullcalendar`?

[image]

I am trying to add that because my target is adding the ff.

```
Right Side : Total of that Row

Left Side : Week 1,Week 2 .....

Bottom : Total of all rows
```

I am using `fullcalendar` and I can make display the data my problem is the custome cells on corners.

Answer (score 0):

According to Fullcalendar.io docs you can implement you custom view from scratch with JS

check more details [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js)

and refer to this property

```
CustomView = View.extend({ // make a subclass of View

  render: function() {
  // responsible for displaying the skeleton of the view within the already-defined
  // this.el, a jQuery element.
  },
  ...
})
```

Comment: I hope you can give an example and i will realy appreciate it